# Grails RestfulController actions and resources

Tags: rest, grails

I'm a bit confused on now this should be working. The documentation says:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#extendingRestfulController

> 9.1.5.1 Extending the RestfulController super class
>
> The easiest way to get started doing so is to create a new controller
>   for your resource that extends the grails.rest.RestfulController super
>   class. For example:

`class BookController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    BookController() {
        super(Book)
    }
}`

> To customize any logic you can just override the appropriate action.
>   The following table provides the names of the action names and the
>   URIs they map to:
>
> HTTP Method   URI Controller Action
>  GET   /books  index
>   GET   /books/create   create
>  POST /books  save
>   GET   /books/${id}    show
>  GET    /books/${id}/edit   edit
>   PUT   /books/${id}    update
>  DELETE   /books/${id}    delete

I have created the BookController as well as the associated Book domain class, but i notice that I cannot access (Bootstrap added books) the books via the documented uri: 
**/books/${id}**

I am able to access it using the non-plural domain name and the action: 
**/book/show/1**

When I try to add @Resource(uri='/books') to the Book domain class that doesn't help either.
Does grails not support his anymore? Do i have to use the action verbs?

I am using grails 2.4.2

Thanks.

Comment: Did you setup `"/books"(resources:"book")` in your `UrlMappings.groovy`?

Comment: You are correct, by adding that in it does work.  Thank you.  It seems that if i use the @Resource in the domain it works as desired.  If i create a controller that extends RestfulController the mappings are overridden with the action bases paths.  The documentation is very misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend `RestfulController` you are responsible for setting up the resource mapping within the `UrlMappings.groovy`. Unlike the `@Resource` annotation on your Domain class.

For example:

```
// UrlMappings.groovy
"/books"(resources:"book")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would be nice if the documentation stated that.  They way all of us here read it;  was implicit.

Comment: We were all being tripped up on the default _"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"_ UrlMapping, thinking something else was registering that explicitly.

Comment: It's okay. Given all the options available it's difficult for some people to understand what the implementation of each approach means. If I get time today I will see about forking the documentation or at least creating a JIRA. Unless you beat me to it. (: